# they are array of 'float', but still cannot be multiplied

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
     weight = [65.35927815614248, 55.78793407606303, 111.63833879205484, 98.63043235014231, 135.42671013218026, 120.99968499739636, 153.07374608221164, 137.72955622024224, 182.20440377291445, 165.5884212527185, 215.3954075146189, 197.69033085244203, 253.36034985426403, 234.87836819253903, 297.02527005128184, 278.279583862876, 348.27438593767295, 330.11235909155596, 429.90523272383, 414.80829759605706, 563.56852141199, 559.9456695948115, 711.6378684503688, 732.2, 800.0, 1000.0]

     density = [672.7815124725854, 807.3378149671024, 743.1474574399257, 891.7769489279108, 768.6673224295163, 922.4007869154195, 784.7817876081614, 941.7381451297937, 807.5138421906755, 969.0166106288107, 829.0334064717503, 994.8400877661003, 849.4902749368802, 1019.3883299242561, 869.0066612216123, 1042.8079934659347, 887.9040017426006, 1065.4848020911209, 911.7041287210849, 1094.0449544653018, 939.8582604051843, 1127.829912486221, 961.498943200003, 1153.7987318400037, 1000.0, 1000.0]



Ans = 46.4 * 10. ** (-36.7 * weight / density)
```

I got the error message: TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

How to resolve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot perform element-wise multiplication like this with python lists. You can convert `weight` and `density` to numpy arrays, and then your code will work. Otherwise, you will need to loop over each element of your arrays and perform your operations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you go:

```py
In [1]: %paste                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
import numpy as np


weight = np.array([65.35927815614248, 55.78793407606303, 111.63833879205484, 98.63043235014231, 135.42671013218026,
 120.99968499739636, 153.07374608221164, 137.72955622024224, 182.20440377291445, 165.5884212527185, 215.3954075146189,
  197.69033085244203, 253.36034985426403, 234.87836819253903, 297.02527005128184, 278.279583862876, 348.27438593767295,
   330.11235909155596, 429.90523272383, 414.80829759605706, 563.56852141199, 559.9456695948115, 711.6378684503688, 732.2,
    800.0, 1000.0])

density = np.array([672.7815124725854, 807.3378149671024, 743.1474574399257, 891.7769489279108, 768.6673224295163,
 922.4007869154195, 784.7817876081614, 941.7381451297937, 807.5138421906755, 969.0166106288107,
  829.0334064717503, 994.8400877661003, 849.4902749368802, 1019.3883299242561, 869.0066612216123, 1042.8079934659347,
   887.9040017426006, 1065.4848020911209, 911.7041287210849, 1094.0449544653018, 939.8582604051843, 1127.829912486221,
    961.498943200003, 1153.7987318400037, 1000.0, 1000.0])



Ans = 46.4 * 10. ** (-36.7 * weight / density)
## -- End pasted text --

In [2]: Ans                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
Out[2]: 
array([1.26238506e-02, 1.35054007e-01, 1.42334203e-04, 4.05043831e-03,
       1.58698733e-05, 7.11616172e-04, 3.22171204e-06, 1.99126584e-04,
       2.43034101e-07, 2.48378246e-05, 1.35301734e-08, 2.36402623e-06,
       5.25712575e-10, 1.62342140e-07, 1.32589442e-11, 7.46280836e-09,
       1.86719328e-13, 1.97692915e-10, 2.29609154e-16, 5.64513457e-13,
       4.57136312e-21, 2.79048715e-17, 3.18865437e-26, 2.38078106e-22,
       2.02543346e-28, 9.25801714e-36])
```

Answer (score 0):

Support Balaji's answer, but I'll explain the issue:

```
>>>weight = [65.35927815614248, 55.78793407606303, 111.63833879205484, 98.63043235014231, 135.42671013218026, 120.99968499739636, 153.07374608221164, 137.72955622024224, 182.20440377291445, 165.5884212527185, 215.3954075146189, 197.69033085244203, 253.36034985426403, 234.87836819253903, 297.02527005128184, 278.279583862876, 348.27438593767295, 330.11235909155596, 429.90523272383, 414.80829759605706, 563.56852141199, 559.9456695948115, 711.6378684503688, 732.2, 800.0, 1000.0]
>>>-36.7 * weight

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

You can't multiply a `list` by a `float` (and multiplying by `int` *n* just duplicates the list *n* times).  `numpy` arrays can do element-wise calculations:

```
>>>weight = np.array(weight)
>>>-36.7 * weight

array([ -2398.68550833,  -2047.41718059,  -4097.12703367,  -3619.73686725,
        -4970.16026185,  -4440.6884394 ,  -5617.80648122,  -5054.67471328,
        -6686.90161847,  -6077.09505997,  -7905.01145579,  -7255.23514228,
        -9298.32483965,  -8620.03611267, -10900.82741088, -10212.86072777,
       -12781.66996391, -12115.12357866, -15777.52204096, -15223.46452178,
       -20682.96473582, -20550.00607413, -26117.10977213, -26871.74      ,
       -29360.        , -36700.        ])
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it in python3 vanilla is to do:

```py
weight = [65.35927815614248, 55.78793407606303, 111.63833879205484, 98.63043235014231, 135.42671013218026, 120.99968499739636, 153.07374608221164, 137.72955622024224, 182.20440377291445, 165.5884212527185, 215.3954075146189, 197.69033085244203, 253.36034985426403, 234.87836819253903, 297.02527005128184, 278.279583862876, 348.27438593767295, 330.11235909155596, 429.90523272383, 414.80829759605706, 563.56852141199, 559.9456695948115, 711.6378684503688, 732.2, 800.0, 1000.0]

density = [672.7815124725854, 807.3378149671024, 743.1474574399257, 891.7769489279108, 768.6673224295163, 922.4007869154195, 784.7817876081614, 941.7381451297937, 807.5138421906755, 969.0166106288107, 829.0334064717503, 994.8400877661003, 849.4902749368802, 1019.3883299242561, 869.0066612216123, 1042.8079934659347, 887.9040017426006, 1065.4848020911209, 911.7041287210849, 1094.0449544653018, 939.8582604051843, 1127.829912486221, 961.498943200003, 1153.7987318400037, 1000.0, 1000.0]

def calculate_answer(w, d):
  return (46.4 * 10 ** (-36.7 * w / d))


answer = [calculate_answer(w, d) for w, d in zip(weight, density)]
```